# Preserving web sockets with Laravel and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, laravel-4, ratchet

I am currently using Ratchet with laravel 4 for my application's chat feature. I am using the following JS in the front-end to handle the web sockets.

```
function startChatSession(){
    var person = prompt("Please enter your ID", "");
    if(chatBoxes.length <= 0)
        chatBoxes.push("onlineList");

    if (person != null && person != "") {
        myself = person;

        if(conn == null){
            conn = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.5:8080?'+person); // 'user facebook id' instead of name
            conn.onmessage = msgReceive;
            conn.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            };
            conn.onerror = function(e){setTimeout(startChatSession,5000);};

        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that the web socket connection disconnects on page refresh and page transition. After searching the web I decided this couldn't be fixed in the front-end. So I want to preserve the chat session at the Laravel's end. I am already storing the online users in the DB, when a connection is opened and deleting them on close.

I am trying to come up with a work around check for online users, since the sockets opens and closes often it creates too many inserts and deletes to table. How can I attach the socket with Laravel session or create a work-around that could solve my problem?